# Trying to strip characters: / and \

Tags: php

I am having issues trying to strip / and \ characters. When i try to strip using \\ it strips \ but when I try /// it doesn't strip / at all.

```
function stripinname( $text )
{
$text = preg_replace(
    array(
        '/\|/','/\"/','/\</','/\>/','/\s[\s]+/','/^[\-]+/','/[\-]+$/','/\%/','/\\\\/','/\////','/\@/','/\&/','/\:/','/\;/','/\-/',
        '@<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>@siu',
        '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu',
        '@<script[^>]*?.*?</script>@siu',
        '@<object[^>]*?.*?</object>@siu',
        '@<embed[^>]*?.*?</embed>@siu',
        '@<applet[^>]*?.*?</applet>@siu',
        '@<noframes[^>]*?.*?</noframes>@siu',
        '@<noscript[^>]*?.*?</noscript>@siu',
        '@<noembed[^>]*?.*?</noembed>@siu',
      // Add line breaks before and after blocks
        '@</?((address)|(blockquote)|(center)|(del))@iu',
        '@</?((div)|(h[1-9])|(ins)|(isindex)|(p)|(pre))@iu',
        '@</?((dir)|(dl)|(dt)|(dd)|(li)|(menu)|(ol)|(ul))@iu',
        '@</?((table)|(th)|(td)|(caption))@iu',
        '@</?((form)|(button)|(fieldset)|(legend)|(input))@iu',
        '@</?((label)|(select)|(optgroup)|(option)|(textarea))@iu',
        '@</?((frameset)|(frame)|(iframe))@iu',
    ),
    array(
        ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',"$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", "$0","$0", "$0",), $text );

// you can exclude some html tags here, in this case B and A tags        
return strip_tags($text);
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using an existing HTML sanitizer?

Comment: Escape sequences would be much more difficult to parse if there were more than one escaping character. You should escape `'/'` with `'\'`, not `'/'`.

Comment: wasn't aware about HTML sanitizer -__- thanks ill try it

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: Charles, how would I go about disallowing / and \ character?

Answer (score 2):

## Don't do this.

Did you know MSIE supports javascript loading from CSS using `behavior:url()`?
Did you know we can execute `javascript:` urls in `<img>` tags?

Use someone else's HTML sanitizer; [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is all right- it has lots of users, and whenever someone finds a bug in it, it gets fixed, and *everyone* using it benefits.

Whereas any bugs in your code (like the one I'm looking at right now) will only be fixed if *you* find it.

I will find a way in.

I always do.

#### Edit:

The reason your code doesn't work is that you don't understand it. Not understanding your program in areas like this *is where* security-related problems come from. Since you have decided I'm just "posting like a big shot", you're ignoring my advice. By doing so, you do a disservice to the entire software developer/engineer industry:

1. You don't understand regular expressions; `,/,` matches slashes.
2. You don't understand how PHP's `preg_replace()` actually matches regular expressions: To match all slashes, you need to match them globally, as in `,/,g`
3. You don't understand that the `/` will appear legitimately inside an HTML tag. By replacing it as you have, I can actually *create* HTML tags that you're attempting to strip.
4. You think `strip_tags()` does what it says on the tin. It doesn't.
5. You've miscounted your arguments. Some of the things you think you are splitting are just getting replaced with themselves.
6. You're not checking for errors. `preg_replace()` can return `NULL`.

You've got so much hubris; you think you've mastered the secrets of this great gig which just involve asking questions on stackoverflow and copying/pasting examples from the PHP wiki. ***You need to stop this***. Writing bug-free programs involves understanding *every* word, and while I'm happy to help you learn how to do this, I'm going to have to insist that you behave responsibly.

#### You should have the ethical sense to avoid writing the code you aren't yet experienced enough to write.

Go get these kinds of routines from a reputable source, and learn from other people's mistakes; Your clients/employers/etc do not deserve your bugs; our industry does not deserve this kind of bullshit.

Comment: You're scaring me a little. *\*locks up children\**

Comment: Oddly enough, the final `strip_tags()` in this function might actually be saving him. That seems almost accidental, though.

Comment: @duskwuff - I'm not convinced: The attempt to remove backslashes smells like he's trying to store the "text" someplace it probably shouldn't be. S/he needs to think about what he's trying to actually accomplish, otherwise he'll forget what all the rules are, and that's how I'll sneak a `');DROP TABLE users;--`

Comment: @geocar I know about XSS and posting like your a "big shot" doesn't help. Duskwuff is right, strip_tags is preventing certain part as stripping HTML codes but, doesn't prevent your attacks whereas I have other functions to protect my site as well.